# ¿Qué registro falta?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Espero me puedan ayudar, llevo rato intentando el obtener el nombre de las personas que hacen falta de registros, hasta ahora solo obtengo el nombre de quienes han registrado.
Mi código es el siguiente, por ahora estoy utilizando un arreglo en el cual tengo almacenados los nombres que requiero y en el query obtengo quienes ya están registrados, según estoy tratando de hacer la comparativa pero ahí es donde tengo el problema.

```
$query = "SELECT edat FROM llenado_formulario WHERE LEFT(fechareg, 10) = LEFT(now(),10) AND fechareg <= '2022-06-14 18:00:00' GROUP BY edat";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $datos = $ver[0];

    $arrayExample = array(
        "Alan Soto",
        "Paloma Razo",
        "Yazmin Albarran",
        "Nallely Quintana"
    );
    $termToSearch = $datos;
    $resultSearch = in_array($termToSearch, $arrayExample);
    if ($resultSearch) {
        echo 'Registros de: ' . $termToSearch .'<br>';
    } 
}
```

Lo que me arroja el query:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! ¿Qué hay en la tabla? Cuál es la estructura de la tabla? Cuál es el problema? Qué debería salir en vez de lo que está en la imagen?

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo @Alfabravo estoy tratando de obtener el nombre de la persona que no aparece en lo que arroja el query... en este caso seria el nombre de Nallely Quintana.

Comment: Pues si quieres los que no estan registrados cambia esto: `$resultSearch = in_array($termToSearch, $arrayExample);` por esto `$resultSearch = !in_array($termToSearch, $arrayExample);`

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta @masterguru acabo de hacer lo que me indicas pero no me imprime nada.

Comment: Mírate mi respuesta a ver si te sirve de algo. No se porque no te funciona eso que te he dicho antes, quizás deberia ser así entonces: `if (!$resultSearch) {` dejando eso como estaba, es decir, `$resultSearch = in_array($termToSearch, $arrayExample);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
$query = "SELECT edat FROM llenado_formulario WHERE LEFT(fechareg, 10) = LEFT(now(),10) AND fechareg <= '2022-06-14 18:00:00' GROUP BY edat";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

$arrayExample = array(
    "Alan Soto",
    "Paloma Razo",
    "Yazmin Albarran",
    "Nallely Quintana"
);

while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    unset($arrayExample[array_search($ver[0], $arrayExample)]);
}

foreach($arrayExample as $noRegistrados) {
    echo 'No registrado: ' . $noRegistrados .'<br>';
}
```

### Cambios realizados

1. Se ha sacado la variable $arrayExample del bucle **while**, pues nos interesa que no se redefina en cada ciclo de nuevo, pues vamos a ir quitándole elementos en los ciclos.
2. Dentro del while se ha agregado esta línea y eliminado todo lo demás:

```
unset($arrayExample[array_search($ver[0], $arrayExample)]);
```

donde:

- [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) nos eliminará un valor del **$arrayExample** en cada ciclo, seleccionado gracias a su índice
- `$arrayExample[array_search($ver[0], $arrayExample)]` apunta al valor indicado por su índice, el cual averiguamos gracias a esta expresión:

```
array_search($ver[0], $arrayExample)
```

donde usamos la función [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php), la cual devuelve el número de índice de lo que se esta buscando (en este caso `ver[0]`, *que apunta al valor de una fila del resultado de la consulta mysql previa*) en el array pasado a la misma (en este caso `$arrayExample`).

Eso nos devolverá un número que indicará su posición de índice, y gracias al **unset()** lo podremos eliminar del array inicial $arrayExample, quedando en cada ciclo menos elementos en él.

3. Finalmente, ya fuera del bucle, recorremos lo que queda de $arrayExample con un bucle [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) y lo mostramos en la salida de este modo:

```
foreach($arrayExample as $noRegistrados) {
    echo 'No registrado: ' . $noRegistrados .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Al hacerlo de la forma que me indicas, solo me trae quienes tienen registros, y con el ! delante de la función no me trae nada.

Comment: **if (!in_array($termToSearch, $arrayExample)) {
        echo 'No hay registros de: ' . $termToSearch .'<br>';
     } else {
        echo 'Registros de: ' . $termToSearch .'<br>';
     }**
Lo hice de esta forma pero se pasa directo al else

Comment: Me ha funcionado de forma correcta @masterguru hice unos cambios en la base para rectificar que los datos arrojados fueran las personas que no están registradas y en efecto, funciono. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Perfecto, otro dia lo documento un poco más para que quede constancia de porque funciona (ahora ya toca retirada :-))  saludos!

Comment: Vale, ya he agregado la explicación pertinente (ayer ya estaba muerto, je, era muy tarde), saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y por la explicación. ¡Saludos!